# Jenkins Job DSL return script results

Tags: shell, maven, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm converting my existing build jobs to be generated by Jenkins Job DSL.

The jobs are primarily Maven based and invoke Sonar. The existing jobs execute a couple of shell commands that make a call to the Sonar server to test if the Sonar run has passed a Sonar Quality Gate. If it passes the Quality Gate, the job proceeds, otherwise it fails. The code block for this is:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Query the Sonar Quality Gate for this project; if good, proceed with the job

APP_GROUPID=$(cat pom.xml  | xpath /project/groupId/text\(\) 2>/dev/null)
APP_ARTIFACTID=$(cat pom.xml  | xpath /project/artifactId/text\(\) 2>/dev/null)

export SONAR_RESULT=$(curl --silent -H "Accept: application/xml"  "http://<sonar-server>/api/resources/index?includealerts=true&metrics=alert_status&resource=${APP_GROUPID}:${APP_ARTIFACTID}" | xpath '/resources/resource/msr/alert/text()' 2>/dev/null)

echo $SONAR_RESULT
if [ "$SONAR_RESULT" == "OK" ]; then
  echo "*** SONAR_RESULT = [$SONAR_RESULT] Proceeding with deployment."
else
  echo "*** SONAR_RESULT = [$SONAR_RESULT] Halting deployment attempt!"
  exit -1
fi
```

I'm trying to replicate this functionality in the Jenkins Job DSL. To do it, I need to get the Maven Group & Artifact ID info, build the command to query the Sonar server, then return the query's result.

I don't see any info in the Job DSL documentation on how to return the status of a shell step. So far the only way I see to do it, is run 1 or more DSL shell step to get the Group + Artifact ID info, formulate the results as Jenkins environment variables & write them to a temporary file; I then inject those variables into the build job; once that's done, I then make the call to the Sonar Server and write the result to another temporary file and examine that. Obviously this is pretty kludgy.

Is there a better way to do it, without necessarily using the shell step?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider re-implementing this part of your build and avoiding the use of a shell step.

If you go to the (excellent) job-dsl api documentation you can see that there is Sonar dsl ready and waiting for you to be used ...

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.MavenPublisherContext.sonar

In my opinion, it would be *better* to make use of the Job DSL that deals with Sonar there rather than running your Sonar tests via a shell script

Your code will have less languages to contend with, be cleaner, easier to maintain and understand.

Comment: Thanks very much Rob, I did look at the Sonar DSL method. In my scenario, I've already run the Sonar analysis with a previous maven call (which could be switched out to use the Job DSL. What I'm looking to do now is basically return a pass/fail to the Jenkins job based on the already completed Sonar run. I couldn't see how the DSL method would accomplish that.